# The "edit tags" link does not appear after editing a question inline

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-tag-editor

After editing a question inline, the "edit tags" link does not appear when hovering over the spot it normally appears:

[image: No edit tags link]

Which is confirmed by looking at the DOM:

[image: before editing]

[image: after editing]

(Also, the "title" attribute of the last tag link is empty.)

This has been tested on Firefox 8.0.1, and Chrome 15.0.874.121.

Comment: This happens on Safari 5.1.1 too. It happens also when clicking on "Save Edits" without having changed anything, while clicking on "cancel" doesn't cause the "edit tags" link to disappear.

Comment: FYI, for those who don't see such a feature: this is only available to 10k-rep users and diamond mods.

Comment: I was about to report the same thing. It's very annoying, but it's resolved by doing a page refresh. Has the team reproduced this problem yet?

Comment: @Oded: `status-reproduced` after one and half year... Very sloooow... :)

Comment: @hims056 guess he saw this only while [killing the retag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179401/152859)... ;)

Comment: @hims056 - what Sha said. Noticed [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#comment540744_177265).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed for the next build.

Will be with you in revision 2013.7.9.826.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this for a while, and recently confirmed this on the following versions of the following browsers:

- Google Chrome - 16.0.912.77m
- Internet Explorer - 9.0.8112.16421
- Safari - 5.12 (7534.52.7)
- Firefox 3.6.13