# Why is inline tag editing not available with retag privileges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

So I just stumbled upon this wizardry: An edit link that appears when I hover over a question's tags, which allows me to quickly edit them without leaving the page.

> [image]

At first, I thought I'd been blind and missed it these past couple months, or maybe it's a new feature. However, it seems that it's been around for a while and is [part of the moderator tools privilege package](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114290/the-edit-tags-link-does-not-appear-after-editing-a-question-inline#comment308370_114290), granted at 10k.

I gotta ask: Is there any reason for this? Seems like it'd be a convenient thing for *everyone* to have. After all, you unlock inline post editing along with edit privileges — why not lower the bar significantly and make this part of the [retag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Jeff [said on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/#comment-45740),

> With inline tagging, you can tag more stuff, faster. This is somewhat dangerous, so we prefer that more experienced users have access to it.

Inline tagging pretty much lacks *any* resistance; you can retag questions so easily and without any extra thinking that it's extremely important that you have enough experience with the site. Tagging is very easy to do wrong, even by high-rep users. We see it every day.

Inline retagging really feels like you're not doing much, while the opposite is obviously true. That's why we'll continue to require lots of experience to allow this, so you're not fooled by the ease.

And, as you noticed yourself, it's an awesome privilege to strive for :)