# Why did the "retag" link disappear underneath questions?

Tags: support, edits, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason for removing the retag link for users with full editing rights?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88151/what-is-the-reason-for-removing-the-retag-link-for-users-with-full-editing-right)

I used to see a retag link below other people's questions on Stack Overflow, but now it's missing!

Instead, I only see `link | edit | flag` there now.

What happened to retag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You earned enough reputation (2k+) to grant you [full editing powers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). Accordingly, the `retag` link you used to see has been replaced with a full fledged `edit` link.

Clicking the `edit` link will allow you to both retag the question as well as edit its title/body. [Use your editing powers wisely](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) to improve the site!

<sub>The only thing left to do now is wait until you earn at least 10k+ reputation, at which point you'll see a [super-secret inline "edit tags" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88151/what-is-the-reason-for-removing-the-retag-link-for-users-with-full-editing-right/88152#88152) in addition to the regular "edit" link under the question.</sub>

Comment: if i edit only to add tag also its appearing as edited xx mins ago with my name.I hate that.

Comment: @Padma: It has *always* appeared that way, even if you used the "retag" link. All edits are saved in the revision history of a post, no matter how small.

Comment: I actually made a screenshot of the "super-secret inline "edit tags" link", and wanted to advice to use this. I was not aware I had this only since I passed the 10k! so +1 for your complete answer.

Comment: And the official reasoning in [Why is inline tag editing not available with retag privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117624/why-is-inline-tag-editing-not-available-with-retag-privileges/126774#126774)