# Why have my "Retag" & "Edit" links been removed from some questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

I've edited and retagged several posts in the past with no problem, but now I've been occasionally noticing that I am unable to retag or edit (some) questions. Any idea why this is?

[THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832290/start-an-app-on-boot-up-on-an-ipad-which-has-been-jailbreaked-ios) for example does not show me the edit or retag links.

[image]

I am below 2000 rep, which I know would explain the retag link disappearing, but not the edit link too. As suggested in [THIS ANSWER.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125120/why-did-the-retag-link-disappear-underneath-questions)
And as far as I can tell, the questions this is happening to are not protected or closed so what gives?!

Has anyone else ran into this situation?

Comment: There was a pending suggested edit on the question.

Comment: That makes sense, and I think that may have been THE quickest response I've ever received! Is there anywhere on SO where they break down these specific little rules and features so that I don't have to bother meta with these trivial questions? I couldn't find this anywhere on SO.

Comment: A majority of the information is lingering here on Meta somewhere, but it's not all easy to find if you aren't sure what you're looking for. That said, searching in [meta-tag:faq] posts can usually get you an answer to most questions you might have.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate it. I pretty extensively searched before posting this, but a majority of my searches were to the effect of "retag button removed." I suppose if I had searched for the edit link disappearing I would have found the post you linked above. If you don't mind posting an answer so I can mark it correct, seeing as you did give me the answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were pending edits on that question. And you **do not** have edit privileges, so the buttons were hidden from you.