# In-line retag disappers after completing an inline edit

Tags: bug, inline-editor, inline-tag-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The “edit tags” link does not appear after editing a question inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114290/the-edit-tags-link-does-not-appear-after-editing-a-question-inline)

Once I complete an edit using inline editing, I see that the in-line tag edit link is no longer visible.

Now it's happened several times that I see a fairly bad post, I immediately click on the inline edit & fix the body & update it, and then I go

[image]

and realize I haven't updated the tags - only to find the in-line tag editor link missing. I do complete both edits within the edit-grace time, so both edits come as a single one.

Can this please be fixed?